# Connected subsets of $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, connectedness

**Question**: Let $V$ be span of $(1,1,1)$ and $(0,1,1)∈\mathbb{R^3}$, let $u_1=(0,0,1)$, $u_2=(1,1,0)$, $u_3=(1,0,1)$ then which of the following are correct?

$1.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(0,0,0)\}$ is not connected.

$2.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ tu_1+(1-t)u_2:0\le t\le 1\}$  is connected.

$3.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ tu_1+(1-t)u_3:0\le t\le 1$} is connected.

$4.(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{(t,2t,2t):t\in \mathbb R$} is connected.

**My attempt**: I know what is definition of connected sets, but usually I had applied the definition to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ but yet i didn't applied it subsets of bigger space $\mathbb{R^3}$. But to start the problem, first I had to find $V$.

Now, $V= span\{(1,1,1),(0,1,1)\}$

$= \{x(1,1,1)+y(0,1,1): x, y ∈\mathbb{R^3}\}$

$=\{(x,x+y,x+y): x,y ∈\mathbb{R}\}$

Now, what will be, $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)$? it's complement of $V$ in bigger space $\mathbb {R^3}$, beyond my imagination!!  Got stuck! From hours, Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $V$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you would consider $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus V$, then you would have divided $\mathbb{R}^3$ into two halves. However, you have added the origin back, so you have two open, connected sets sharing a point, making the first one a connected space.

For the other three sets $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus V \cup A$ (with $A$ the sets defined in your problem), try to find out if these sets intersect $V$ or not. If they do intersect $V$, the space becomes connected by the same reasoning as in $(1)$. If the sets do not intersect $V$, then you have a disconnected set.

**EDIT:** your question is exactly the same as the [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044516/if-mathbb-r3-setminus-v-connected-where-v-is-the-subspace-generated-by?rq=1) one, which has been answered apparently.

**SECOND EDIT**: Consider (for example) $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the $xy$-plane removed, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{(x,y,0) \vert x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. The space you obtain from this operation is $$\{(x,y,z) \vert x,y \in \mathbb{R}, z > 0\} \cup \{(x,y,z) \vert x,y \in \mathbb{R}, z < 0\}$$
both of them being open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and hence also in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the $xy$-plane removed), they form a separation of the space (a separation of a space $X$ is a disjoint union of open subset $U,V$). Note that the space $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus V$ is homeomorphic (read "the same") to the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the $xy$-plane removed.

You also asked me to do one of the last three. Let me give a 'hint' for $(3)$ and $(4)$: what happens if you set $t = 0$?

Comment: Sir, I get about the first option but still unable to imagine graphically how $\mathbb {R^3}$(three dimensional space) is divided into two halves:-( further, if possible could you do any 'one' of last three options.

Comment: I will edit my answer, hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Sir, thank for Second edit, you make it clear to see. Sir that post you mention in your answer says, $\left(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus V\right) \cup S$ will be connected if and only if $S\cap V\neq\emptyset$ but I didn't get it! Why the intersection with $V$ must be non-empty?

Comment: Normally, you should ask this as a separate question, but this one is quite short: if there is a point in $S \cap V$, then you add this piont to $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus V$. This gives you the situation of $(1)$. The converse follows from the same reasoning.

Comment: If I set $t=0$ in (2) then, $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ tu_1+(1-t)u_2:0\le t\le 1\}=(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ u_3\}$

Comment: I meant $(3)$, sorry for that one

Comment: Sir, If I set $t=0$ in (3), I get $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)\cup \{ u_2\}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74147/discussion-between-student-and-akash-patalwanshi).

Comment: Sir, there was typo in (3), I had edited it.

Comment: Note that $u_1 + u_2 = (1,1,1)$, does this help for $(3)$?

Comment: Didn't get you sir :-(

Comment: yes, this helps, since if we then consider $\frac{1}{2}(u_1 + u_2)$, this element is an element of $V$ (it is a scalar multiple of one of the spanning vectors) and it also is an element of the set $A$. Hence the line intersects $V$ and as in $(1)$, the space is connected.

Comment: I think you are saying about $u_1+ u_2=(1,11)$ but then?

Comment: Sir, how $(1/2)(u_1+u_2)$ is member of that set $A$

Comment: take $t = 1/2)$

Comment: Sir, may be I am wrong, would you like to check this, $(\mathbb R^3\backslash V)= \{(x,y,z)∈\mathbb{R}: z>y or z<y\}$ is am I correct?